# Geometric Random Variable Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

[image]

I don't understand how to solve for the PMF. It's giving me trouble because in the usual geometric problem we know that the constraint on trials is from 1 to infinity. However in this case it's 2 to infinity. Furthermore I don't understand how you get the probability of the number of trials before a success in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let our random variable, the count of tosses until termination, be denoted as $N$.

If the termination is the first occurance of two consecutive tosses of the same result, then you must toss a pattern like $\sf\ldots THTHTHTT$ or $\sf\ldots HTHTHTHH$ .   Ie: Always alternating until the very end.   Obviously.

So, to stop on toss # $2k$, for any $k\in\{1,2,\ldots\}$, you must toss either: $k-1$ consecutive $\sf TH$ *pairs* then a $\sf TT$ pair, *or* $k-1$ consecutive $\sf HT$ pairs then a $\sf HH$ pair.   So what is $\mathsf P(N=2k)$ ?

Likewise to stop on toss # $2k+1$, for any $k\in\{1,2,\ldots\}$, you must toss either: $k$ consecutive $\sf TH$ pairs then a single $\sf H$, *or* $k$ consecutive $\sf HT$ pairs then a single  $\sf T$ .   So what is $\mathsf P(N=2k+1)$ ?

Then you have a piecewise function for your probability depending on whether the count you seek is even or odd. $$\mathsf P(N{=}n) ~=~ \begin{cases} \color{green}{\underline{\qquad}} &:& n\in 2\Bbb N^+ \\[1ex] \color{green}{\underline{\qquad}} &:& n\in 2\Bbb N^+{+}1\end{cases}$$